# How to increase icon size in OpenTTD

Tags: openttd

Is there a way to increase icon size (e.g. the menu icons) in OpenTTD? The default size is much to small for high pixel density screens (e.g. 17" Laptop with 1920x1200).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try using the [Big GUI NewGRF](http://www.tt-forums.net/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=50095), which doubles the size of all GUI components in the game.

First, download the NewGRF package:

[image]

Next, activate the NewGRF package by using the 'add' button and apply changes.

Comment: Oh by the way: It will be *your* fault if I get nothing done this weekend!!! ;-)

Comment: Doens't affect existing games, anyway to fix?